# C# Selenium how can I apply sendkeys operation to this field

Tags: c#, .net, selenium-webdriver

Normally we can print text to input fields very easily with sendkeys. There is a field on my website where text is written, but it is not input. I am sharing the code of this field.

```
<p role="document" aria-multiline="true" aria-label="Absatz-Block" class="block-editor-rich-text__editable block-editor-block-list__block wp-block is-selected wp-block-paragraph rich-text" id="block-c0925452-83ce-4b01-b3c1-386674a16bd0" data-block="c0925452-83ce-4b01-b3c1-386674a16bd0" data-type="core/paragraph" data-title="Absatz" data-empty="false" contenteditable="true" style="white-space: pre-wrap; min-width: 1px;">sample text</p>
```

I tried to send it with fullxpath as below but I was not successful. When I get normal xpath instead of full, it gives id and this id is constantly changing.

**My code:**

```
string text = "<!-- wp:table -->\n<figure class=\"wp-block-table\">";
var info3 = drv.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[2]/p"));
info3.SendKeys(text);
```

How can I send text to this non-input field with seleinum

Comment: Instead of using the full xpath or xpath using the dynamic ID, maybe you can use the text of the element (e.g. `//p[text()='sample text']`). Also since you mentioned it was not successful when using the full xpath, it would be better to include the error you encountered so others can better understand